# Using React, when clicking on Back button, the view is updating correctly but the URL is not

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am working on a React Redux project and am having difficulty getting the URL to correctly update to align with the view being displayed when clicking on a "Back" button. Regardless of where the "Back" button takes you back to, the URL is always displaying as "Dashboard", even when the view is not the "Dashboard". I am pretty new to both React and Redux (and fairly new to Javascript/Typescript) so I am not sure exactly what is happening here, but there is a Switch statement in the routes.tsx file as shown below:

```
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/Dashboard" />
    {categoryLayouts}
    <CoreLayout exact path="/error" component={ErrorPageComponent} />
    <CoreLayout exact path="/unauthorized" component={UnauthorizedMessageComponent} />
  </Switch>
```

If I change "Dashboard" to another view's name, then the URL displays the change when you go back using the "Back" button, but the view displayed is still correct.

I have a feeling this is where a change needs made, but am struggling to figure out what exactly is going on here and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: All direct descendents of a `Switch` must be either `Route` or `Redirect`. Everything else is going to cause bugs and basically make it non-functional. This is even the case if you put in a simple wrapping component which only returns `Route` components.

Answer (score 0):

The comment on your question has already informed you why it isn't working -> direct children of Switch has to be Route or Redirect.

More than that, your "CoreLayout" should be done in the parent of Router, whatever is consuming router.  Router should only be responsible for "routing" -> single responsibility.

If any specific layout stuff can't be done in the parent of Router then do that specifically in the component for that route, i.e. a sidebar.